# How can I programmatically backup Android phone's settings?

Tags: settings, backup, automation

I was wondering if I could programmatically backup my Android phone's settings. The "PHONE"'s settings and not application settings.

Comment: TitaniumBackup allows scheduled jobs that can e.g. save to the cloud, see http://matrixrewriter.com/android/

Comment: Just to clarify: what do you mean by the 'Phone' settings. You can back up SMS etc with MyBackup (as mentioned below), you can use Tasker Scripts for others, you can back up third party launcher internally in the launcher. Google will backup your contacts, app data and WiFi passwords. What else are you looking to backup? If you are rooted I recommend paying for Titanium Backup. It is an absolute life saver!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way availaboe to you is using a third party app. I found [My Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro) (there is a free version as well) which seemed promising.

You can also search he market for settings backup.

<sup>I use an system app provided by the manufacturer which is called backup and restore. I'll give them if the mentioned solution does not work for you. The reason im asking you to go with the first app is that the manufacturer's system app is highly unlikely to work properly ina device other than the one is originally made for.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is an LG, it's easy to do that with LG backup. To backup your phone's settings, go to Settings - LG Backup [in list mode] - Backup. Unselect everything except settings, and click backup.

If not, try Titanium Backup.

Comment: BTW you can do this automaticly, but you cant choosewhat to backup

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. It seems some of your answers lack detail and might get downvoted or even deleted. Consider [edit]ing and explaining the step on *how to do it automatically*, including on your other answers. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the location of the settings database, you can use [LlamaLab's Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/) to copy app data within the application itself, even in the root directory.

Comment: I believe this needs root access since app data is located on the internal storage.

Comment: Can you tell how to do that exactly? Automate is a multi-feature app and not straightforward to use.